# Click through transparent Panel: Difference between Debug and Exe

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging, visual-studio-2013, click-through

I have a little screenshot program, which has a transparent Panel (using TransparencyKey) at its center.

It works fine but I noticed a strange difference between the compiled version and the one I get when running it from VS with `VS Host process` activated in the project properties.

With the latter I can click through the Panel. But the Exe doesn't do that and turning off `VS Host process activated` also shields the background from the mouse.

Why is that so? Is there a (cheap) trick to make it work in the exe as well?

(Running VS Express 2013 on W8.1,64bit, all effects turned off)

**Edit: Resolved (?!?)**

Changing the transparency key color to (any) predefined color indeed seems to make a difference:

```
pan_hole.BackColor = Color.Fuchsia;  // .FromArgb(255, 242, 23, 199);
this.TransparencyKey = pan_hole.BackColor;
```

Red, Green, Yellow or LavenderBlush :-) work as well.

This is crazy. It'll take months for me to believe it..!

Comment: Seems like this is related with [aero (metro may have the same bug)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448771/c-sharp-form-transparencykey-working-different-for-different-colors-why)

Comment: Yes, indeed there seems to be a relation, although, as it is with bugs, their nature isn't easily understood. See my edit!