# Transparent Windows Form that can handle Click

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm working in C#, in Visual Studio, and I'm trying to make a **transparent form** - entirely transparent, though **not click-through** - without making the title bar transparent, so that there's still something to move the (invisible) window around and (most importantly) close it.

It'd also be nice if the window had visible borders, but that may be a separate question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can Use [`TrancparencyKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.transparencykey?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8)

Set `TrancparencyKey` and `BackColor` properties both to same color like `Color.Red`.

Here is the screenshot of transparent form over visual studio:

[image]

Note:

- When you use for example `Color.Red` every thing works fine and you can handle mouse `Click`. But the behavior is different for different colors, for example `Color.Magenta` the form can not capture the mouse `Click`.

Comment: Both settings can be found under Properties of your Form.

Comment: On my system (Windows 10 with VS Community 2015) I did not need the `this.Capture` part.  The Form was transparent in the middle, but already capturing the mouse click by default (I updated the click position in the Form's title bar).

Comment: @Idle_Mind When you use for example `Color.Red` every thing works fine and also it seems there is no need to set `Capture=true`. Behavior is different for different colors, for example `Color.Magenta` the form can not capture the mouse click.

Comment: That is *weird*. I assume there's something underlying that, I'll have to dig into it...

Comment: @link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448771/c-sharp-form-transparencykey-working-different-for-different-colors-why