# How to make a child form transparent?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

So I have a multiple forms and one main form. I show the child forms through a panel. I was wondering if I could make the child forms transparent, that way it would blend in with my background image. Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Prepare your form and panel

Set your panel

```
// 
// panel1
// 
this.panel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlDark;
```

And your form

```
// 
// Form1
//
this.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlDark;
this.TransparencyKey = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
```

Now add child forms

```
Form form = new Form()
{
    TopLevel = false
};
panel1.Controls.Add(form);
form.Show();
```

Read also

- [Form.TransparencyKey property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.transparencykey?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)
- [Form.TopLevel Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.toplevel?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

And remember, if you set **red** color to `TransparencyKey` and `BackColor` of your form and controls then they will be able to handle mouse events. This is only in case of **red** color. In other cases Any mouse actions, such as the click of the mouse, that are performed on the transparent areas of the form will be transferred to the windows below the transparent area. For example, if the client region of a form is made transparent, clicking the mouse on that area would send the event notification of the click to any window that is below it. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448771/c-sharp-form-transparencykey-working-different-for-different-colors-why) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32783183/transparent-windows-form-that-can-handle-click?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: I still want it to show my background image in Form 1 not making it completely transparent.

Comment: Try `this.panel1.BackgroundImage = myImage;`. I mean set your image to panel, not form.

Comment: The panel image will have an offset from form1, which doesnt look good

Comment: Make adjustments to your panel layout. You can, for example, dock it filling. If there are padding in client area of your form then remove it, so on and son... Make adjustments.

Comment: Also take into account the size of your image and `BackgroundImageLayout` property of your panel.