# How to change form borders size when the form TransparencyKey is set to Color.LimeGreen?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making the form1 to be transparent but i want to keep the borders and to be able to change the borders size.

The problem is when changing the form size because it's transparent the mouse loose the control over it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Testings
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen;
            this.TransparencyKey = Color.LimeGreen;

            this.SizeChanged += Form1_SizeChanged;
        }

        private void Form1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }            
    }
}
```

I tried in the Form1_SizeChanged to add :

```
this.TransparencyKey = SystemColors.Window;
this.TransparencyKey = Color.LimeGreen;
```

like this :

```
private void Form1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.TransparencyKey = SystemColors.Window;
            this.TransparencyKey = Color.LimeGreen;
        }
```

So it was working at the start but after few times i changed the form size it started blinking between the Window color and the LimGreen color and then lost the control again and i could not drag and change the form size again even if i see the top border but can't touch it with the mouse.

This is a screenshot of the form when it's transparent.

[image: transparent form]

There are two problems :

- after some time the mouse lost control over the form top border and can't touch it drag it or change it's size because it's becoming transparent too after changing the size few times.
- there is only the top border for now, how can i make that also the other borders will be shown ? left,right,bottom ?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use another color. In this case red. It seems that each color is behaving different. When setting to red you can resize the transparent form in all directions and drag it around.

This is cool. The next thing to do is to use ffmpeg to record the transparent form area. this way i can record specific parts of the desktop.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Testings
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.BackColor = Color.Red;
            this.TransparencyKey = Color.Red;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is a useful bug! Isn't it? See [C# Form.TransparencyKey working different for different colors, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448771/c-sharp-form-transparencykey-working-different-for-different-colors-why).